# Grant permission to www-data to write to json-file

Tags: python, php, json, permissions, permission-denied

I'm trying to make a simple (locally hosted) webpage that calls on a python script to generate a list of random numbers and display them in the browser.

This is generate.php (neglecting enclosing html)

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    //DEBUG
    $pythonExec = '/usr/local/bin/python3';
    $pythonScript = 'gen_array.py';

    clearstatcache();
    if (!file_exists($pythonExec)) {
        exit("The python executable '$pythonExec' does not exist!");
    }
    if (!is_executable($pythonExec)) {
        exit(("The python executable '$pythonExec' is not executable!"));
    }
    if (!file_exists($pythonScript)) {
        exit("The python script file '$pythonScript' does not exist!");
    }

    // Execute it, and redirect STDERR to STDOUT to display error messages
    exec("$pythonExec \"$pythonScript\" 2>&1", $output);

    // Show the output of the script
    print_r($output); 

    $json_data = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/data.json');
    // Decoding the JSON data to obtain a PHP array
    $php_array = json_decode($json_data, true);

    foreach ($php_array as $element) {
        echo $element . "\n";
    }
?>
```

This is gen_array.py

```
import numpy as np
import json

array = np.random.uniform(1.0, 100.0, 10)
a = array.tolist()

# Writing the list to a JSON file
with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(a, json_file)
```

[Error 13 in Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGOx8.png)

To pass the list from python to php, a json file is generated and processed into an array on the php end. When I open generate.php in my browser, I get Error 13 indicating no permission to generate and write to data.json. I've done some searching and come up with the reason being that server is trying to accomplish this as user 'www-data' with no permission to write this json-file to my disk. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find out how to circumvent this. How could I grant the necessary permissions? I'm on macOS, running an apache Webserver via XAMPP.

I'm still new to anything dynamic-web. I realise this specific task could easily be completed without external python-scripts, this only serves as an example for me to familiarise. Later, I'll need to do more complicated data analysis that I'm uncomfortable with doing outside of python.

Edit: The additional complaint "null given" appears because I ran gen_array.py in terminal, then deleted the entries in the json-file to see whether running it in browser would write new random numbers to the json-file. It didn't, so this is an empty json-file.

Comment: write the file in a directory that is likely to have write permissions

Comment: I've gone ahead and gave read&write permission to everyone in the htdocs directory. Unfortunately the issue remains. Are those the write permissions you're talking about?

Comment: When running the script from terminal it has no problem accessing the json file. Apparently there is such a thing as a temp folder. Would there be a different set of permissions in place for this one? Also [link](https://osxdaily.com/2018/08/17/where-temp-folder-mac-access/) is very vocal about not messing around in there...?

Comment: yes, tmp is bad. if it works on terminal, maybe try prefixing with `sudo`, and make sure the file is being written where you want it to be. maybe use absolute path for that.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but I expect I'll need to add www-data to the list of users with sudo privileges first. The file is written in the right place, the php-file is able to retrieve it just fine (having run the python part in terminal once to create data.json), however it never changes the random numbers upon refreshing since it can't write to data.json. Might there be a way to grant writing privileges to the apache user in a config file somewhere?

Comment: it isn't a good practice to add php to sudo. it is better to set write permissions and or ownership of folder to apache user.

Comment: Alright got it! I hadn't applied the writing permissions to enclosed items. See here [link](https://support.apple.com/en-hk/guide/mac-help/mchlp1203/mac#:~:text=On%20your%20Mac%2C%20select%20a,then%20choose%20a%20privilege%20setting.) for info. One last question: I've just granted "everyone" writing privileges to the htdocs folder and its items. Is this a wise thing to do in terms of security?